# SQL request work on PhpMyAdmin, not on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I can't understand why my request doesn't work when I execute it from PHP, but work perfectly when I copy/past it on the PhpMyAdmin SQL form.

```
UPDATE dg23dwp_tree 
SET id_parent = 1, 
path = 'Documents/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp' 
WHERE path = "Documents/H.C.R 3292/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp";
```

My table is a representation on a file tree. 
I'm moving the file `Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp` into the upper folder.

The request work fine from PHP for other file. I think that something doesn't like the double space after my hyphen.

I dont get any kind of error executing the request from PHP, but my database isn't update.

**EDIT :**
I've forget to past my php code

```
// set before on the process
$from = "Documents/H.C.R 3292/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp";
$to = "Documents/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp";
$parentId = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE dg23dwp_tree SET id_parent = ".$parentId.", path = '".addslashes($to)."' WHERE path = \"".(string)addslashes($from)."\";";
$sql_p = "UPDATE dg23dwp_tree SET id_parent = :id_parent, path = :new_path WHERE path = :old_path;";

var_dump( $sql ); // use to copy/past on PhpMyAdmin

// TEST 1
return $db->query( $sql );

// TEST 2
$db = ConBDD::getInstance();
$prepare = $db->prepare($sql_p);
$prepare->bindValue(':id_parent', $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepare->bindValue(':new_path', $to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepare->bindValue(':old_path', $from, PDO::PARAM_STR);
return $prepare->execute();

// TEST 3
$res = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $res);
return mysql_query($sql);
```

**EDIT 2 :** Here is an export of the code that don't work, with the database.

```
<?php
/* MySQL database sample *\

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dg23dwp_tree` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `indexed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2025 ;

INSERT INTO `dg23dwp_tree` (`id`, `id_parent`, `name`, `size`, `date`, `path`, `indexed`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Documents', NULL, '2016-12-08 17:08:46', 'Documents', 1),
(3, 1, 'Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp', 2100, '2016-12-08 17:08:46', 'Documents/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp', 1),
(16, 1, 'Gestion du dossier.xlsx', 73163, '2016-12-08 17:08:46', 'Documents/Gestion du dossier.xlsx', 1),
(18, 1, 'H.C.R 3292', NULL, '2016-12-08 17:08:46', 'Documents/H.C.R 3292', 1);

*/

    $db = ConBDD::getInstance();
    $from = "Documents/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp";
    $to = "Documents/H.C.R 3292/Anne Laure -  Nouveau.rdp";

    $arrP = explode("/", $to);
    foreach( $arrP as $k => $a ) {
        if(in_array($a, array("", ".", "..")))
            unset($arrP[$k]);
    }
    ksort($arrP);
    $parentPath = implode("/", array_slice($arrP, 0, -1));

    $parentId = $db->query("SELECT id FROM dg23dwp_tree WHERE path = '".addslashes($parentPath)."'")->fetch()['id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE dg23dwp_tree SET id_parent = ".$parentId.", path = '".addslashes($to)."' WHERE path = \"".(string)addslashes($from)."\";";
    $sql_p = "UPDATE dg23dwp_tree SET id_parent = :id_parent, path = :new_path WHERE path = :old_path;";

    $prepare = $db->prepare($sql_p);
    $prepare->bindValue(':id_parent', $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepare->bindValue(':new_path', $to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prepare->bindValue(':old_path', $from, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prepare->execute();

    // LITE version of the db class
    class ConBDD {
        private $PDOInstance = null;

        private static $instance = null;

        private function __construct() {
            $this->PDOInstance = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dsp_frontend;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
        }
        public static function getInstance() {
            if(is_null(self::$instance))
                self::$instance = new ConBDD();
            return self::$instance;
        }
        public function query($query) {
            return $this->PDOInstance->query($query);
        }
        public function prepare($query) {
            return $this->PDOInstance->prepare($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: So, in PHP your request is not the same as in phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1):

If your query can't get exact string from table as given in where condition, the query can't execute. So please check where the condition in where is become true or not.
The other reason may be due to space in string also.

Comment: I've alredy check it before making this post, and yes i've my row on the table `where path = "Documents/H.C.R 3292/Anne Laure -   Nouveau.rdp";`